# Integrate angularjs in Devise-invitable

Tags: angularjs, devise-invitable

I am using devise invitable to invite users to my application.
It is working fine.Recently I switched to angular and I am new to angular
please help me how to invite users through angular in rails application.

Comment: First: StackOverflow is not the place where people write code for you. Second: You should show what approach you have tried so far (i.e. post relevant code) and ask a more specific question when you are stuck at some point and need a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

myApp.factory 'User', ($resource) ->
    $resource '/users/:id.json', {id: '@id'},
        index: 
            method: 'GET'
            responseType: 'json'
            isArray: true
            cache: true

myApp.controller 'usersController', ($scope, User) ->
    $scope.users = User.index()

```
$scope.inviteUser = ->
    user = User.save($scope.newUser)
    $scope.users.push user
    $scope.user = {}
```

This is the code i have in my users.js.coffee